# Displaying all nodes in Linked List

Tags: java

This is part of Linked List class to display all nodes.

What this method is trying to do is set the front (yes, I am using front instead of head which doesn't matter but I'm implementing linked list based queue) to a pointer, in this case called "cur" and check if cur next node is not null, if it is not then get the element (two parts, share and price) and set the cur to the next node, rinse and repeat until it the next cur (before it steps into) is null, in that case it exits the loop and just print that last cur (before the null aka tail/rear). Add all elements to s (by concatenating)

```
public Object displayAll() {
        Node cur = front;
        Object s = null;
        while(cur.getNext() != null) {
             s += cur.getShare() + " @ " + cur.getPrice();
            cur.setNext(cur);
        }
        s += cur.getShare() + " @ " + cur.getPrice();
        return s;
}
```

**Output**: It repeats the first element countless times.
**Intended Output**: I don't want the repetition but display all elements of all nodes.

What am I missing? Any pointers please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(cur.getNext() != null) {             
   s += cur.getShare() + " @ " + cur.getPrice();
   cur = cur.getNext();
}
```

I have assigned `cur = cur.getNext()` are you were not re-assigning `cur` to next node. Also I have removed `cur.setNext(cur);`

You were getting infinite loop because in the while condition you were checking that the next node should not be `null` but no where in the loop you were assigning the `cur = next`, so due to that you remain on the first node and *loop infinitely*.

Comment: Thanks, silly mistake in my part. If I was to adjust your code, I would put cur = cur.getNext(); in the second line of the loop and not first cause I want to also display the front's element. Your immediately setting the cur pointer to the next and ultimately not displaying the front's element too.

Comment: I also set s to a blank string rather than null.

Comment: I have edited the answer to make it the second line. Silly mistake on my part too :)

Comment: Thanks again for the correction, forgot to set it to getNext.

Answer (score 1):

`cur.setNext(cur)` looks pretty suspicious, like you're setting a node to link to itself, which is obviously an infinite relationship.